# by covering your pan with an inch of oil - depth or length

Tags: oil, potatoes, chips

www,wikihow.com/Make-Potato-Chips

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Usually 1 inch of oil is the depth of oil in the pan.

I don't know how you could measure adding 1 inch of oil lengthwise to a pan.

Comment: Apparently you understand the question. Otherwise you wouldn't be posting an answer.

Comment: ... lengthwise might be a puddle of an inch in diameter, but that would be difficult to "cover" a pan with, even with thinning caused by heat.